# String tokenisation algorithm won't tokenise

Tags: xml, bash, token, ifs

Morning all,
I am writing a bash script to extract the values of certain XML tags from all files in a given directory.  I have decided to do this by tokenising each line and returning th4e relavent token.  The problem is that it isn't tokenising correctly and I can't quite work out why.  Here is the smallest example that I could make that reconstructs the issue

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls $MY_DIRECTORY`
do
    for line in `cat $MY_DIRECTORY/$file`
    do
        LOCALIFS=$IFS
        IFS=<>\"

        TOKENS=( $line )
        IFS=$LOCALIFS
        echo "Token 0: ${TOKENS[0]}" 
        echo "Token 1: ${TOKENS[1]}" 
        echo "Token 2: ${TOKENS[2]}" 
        echo "Token 3: ${TOKENS[3]}" 

    done
 done
```

I'm guessing the issue is to do with my fiddling with IFS inside a loop which itself uses IFS (i.e. the cat operation), but this has never been a problem before.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rik

Comment: Please give asn example line from the file and descrivbe how the output is incorrect

Comment: Many beginner mistakes (`for i in $(ls)`, UUOC...) here. See [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a better tool to parse xml, ideally it should be a parser, but if your requirement is simple and you know how your xml is structured, simple string manipulation might suffice. For example, xml file and you want to get value of `tag3`

```
$  cat file
blah
<tag1>value1 </tag1>
<tag2>value2 </tag2>
<tag3>value3
</tag3>
blah

$ awk -vRS="</tag3>" '/tag2/{ gsub(/.*tag3>/,"");print}' file
value3
```

so to iterate over your directory

```
for file in *.xml
do
  value="$(awk -vRS="</tag3>" '/tag2/{ gsub(/.*tag3>/,"");print}' "$file" )"
  echo "$value"
done
```

Comment: I took the liberty to put quotes in your answer, hope you won't be offended.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't matter, since you can always put quotes later on for "value"